# Clean/Precise script to Install GDAL+ECW drivers in QGIS 3.22.16 and Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gdal, r, qgis-3, ecw, ubuntugis

This is what I did so far:

This is how I installed ecw drivers and gdal:

```
#ECW (BORRAR ANTES LA CARPETA /usr/local/hexagon si existía
## Unzip ECW libraries and install. Está en la carpeta public de GoogleDrive
sudo unzip erdas-ecw-sdk-5.4.0-linux.zip
sudo chmod +x ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.4.0.bin
./ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.4.0.bin
sudo rm ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.4.0.bin

## Copy new libraries to system folder
## Rename the newabi library as x64 and move necessary libraries to /usr/local/lib
sudo cp -r ~/hexagon/ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.4.0/Desktop_Read-Only /usr/local/hexagon
# Make symbolic link to libNCSEcw.so.5.4.0
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Desktop_Read-Only/lib/newabi/x64/release/libNCSEcw.so.5.4.0 /usr/local/lib/libNCSEcw.so.5.4.0

# Download and install proper PROJ version 
# QGIS 3.22.4 uses gdal 8.2.1 
# from https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/releases. and unzip it - también está en recursos
sudo unzip proj-8.2.1.zip
cd proj-8.2.1; sudo mkdir build
cd build; sudo cmake ..
sudo make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install

## Download GDAL v3.5.1 Source (ex. 3.5.1) 
## Build GDAL with ECW support (this will take a while...)
# descargar: wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/3.5.1/gdal351.zip
unzip gdal351.zip; cd gdal-3.5.1
./configure --with-ecw=/usr/local/hexagon
sudo make clean && sudo make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install

# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that recompiled GDAL is used
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib

# Set variables (not sure about this...)
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib' >> ~/.profile
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib' >> ~/.bashrc
GDAL_DATA="/usr/local/share/gdal"
sudo ldconfig

# Check if ECW is installed
gdalinfo --formats | grep ECW
```

And this is what I get:

```
gdalinfo --formats | grep ECW
  ECW -raster- (rw+): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.4)
  JP2ECW -raster,vector- (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.4)
```

This is the installed qgis:
[image]

When I try to load ecw into qgis this is what I get:
[image]

But, the same file works ok with my R installation:
[image]

I guess that the solution is to change the gdal version that QGIS is using. QGIS is using the 3.4.1 I guess it comes compiled with it, but I installed the gdal 3.5.1 (if fact I'd like to install the latest 3.6.2 but I couldn't do it). Is this the way to go and how ?

**Update 2023/02/09** (suboptimal solution)

The following solved the issue but I know is not an optimal solution as **this creates duplicates of libraries**. If I copy the files from where gdal and ecw drivers where installed directly to the `/lib`, where QGIS seems to have install his version of gdal, the ecw's can be loaded by qgis...

```
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/* /lib/
```

This is what I see now:
[image]
[image]

I guess that now the question is, how can install ECW drivers and GDAL in a more clean way...

Comment: Do you see ECW now in QGIS Settings - Data Sources - GDAL - Raster drivers? If you don't, the title "ECW doesn't work" should rather be "How to get ECW driver into QGIS".

Comment: QGIS doesn't have GDAL "compiled in" but dynamically links it at runtime - you can see where its linking too with `ldd /usr/bin/qgis.bin | grep gdal` assuming qgis is installed same as me. You can modify the linking by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: This is what I receive with that: libgdal.so.30 => /lib/libgdal.so.30 (0x00007fa0f12c4000)

Comment: I cant download erdas ecw SDK anymore from hexagon website. We are screw...d